# How to stop my Android NFC app looping when it is close to NFC (smartcard)

Tags: android, nfc

My Android nfc app, when it has finished reading a smart card, is presented again with the same NFC tag info and gets launched again by the operating system. In fact if you don't move the phone it goes into a permanent loop.
The amount of data being read does take one or two seconds so at the end it starts again.
(This is fairly common on my Galaxy S2 Gingerbread and my S3 on ICS)

**How do I stop it repeating when the NFC source (smart card) didn't change and was not moved away from the phone?**

My activity has an intent filter of:

```
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/filter_nfc" />
```

With a tech list of

```
 <tech-list>
     <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
 </tech-list>
```

The source code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    resolveIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                 || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        ....work
        handled = true;
    }
    if (!handled) {
        Log.e(tag, "Unknown intent " + intent);
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could solve it was to place a time check - inside the onCreate (setContentView line and resolveIntent line) and also inside the onNewIntent function.

This did not stop Android from trying to call the app again to process the NFC but my app did not do anything if it was called within 2 seconds from the last successful NFC read.

Maybe not the cleanest way but it is effective against the looping problem and passes all the tests on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal, but I have seen similar behaviour, too. What I tried was to enable NFC foreground dispatching. This gives your app complete control over the incoming NFC intents. Then based on the ID of the tag (or perhaps on the time elapsed since the last NFC event) you can decide to ignore the tag.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  ...
  ForegroundDispatch.setupForegroundDispatch(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  ...
  ForegroundDispatch.stopForegroundDispatch(this);
};

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  ... // check for the tag's ID or elapsed time to determine how to react
}
```

Comment: Thanks again NFC guy! This problem was very difficult as certain phones and certain cards showed it when others didn't - my solution is below. I do use foreground dispatch and the ID read wasn't always reliable - so I had to make use of a time delay to ignore other requests. Once the second one was ignored it seemed to stopped the eternally looping!